# Send Graphs in Outlook

Tags: python, vba, outlook-restapi

I wanted to create better automated reports by including visuals rather than just text. The specific way I wanted to do it was by referencing `outlook.application` via `win32com.client`.

I know the basics of sending an email, and I've tried reading through the VBA reference and the closest I found was a [View Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.view), but what I was looking for was the ability to add pie charts, bar graphs etc.

I know through the GUI, once in an open message popped out from the application you can `Insert > Chart` and select the desired chart to load into the message.

Is there a way in the outlook API to be able to utilize these graphs/charts that are available in the `Insert Chart` window? Or is the API relatively limited in features available compared to the application when it comes to message styling/formatting?

Here's the bare-bones code for how the message is created/sent, I was wanting to add these visuals to the message body.

```
import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

mail.To = 'some@name'
mail.Subject = 'Subject'
mail.Body = 'Body'
# or 
mail.HTMLBody = '<h2>HTML body</h2>' 

mail.Send()
```

---

***Update***

I'm currently looking into it more, but I found this for vba that's supposed to do what I'm looking for. I've been messing around with chart objects a bit in excel as well. Here's the code I need to understand

```
Sub CopyAndPasteToMailBody()
    Set mailApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set mail = mailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    mail.Display
    Set wEditor = mailApp.ActiveInspector.wordEditor
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    wEditor.Application.Selection.Paste
End Sub
```

---

Here's some bare bones code I have that will create a chart object:

```
from win32com import client

excel = client.Dispatch("excel.application")
excel.Visible = True
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets.Add()
chs = ws.ChartObjects()
co = chs.Add(0,0,500,500)
```

---

***Update***

Below I have answered how to spawn a chart in Excel and have it sent through Outlook. It is not the 'Outlook API', as it's Office as a whole that must be utilized. If you were confused like I was by a lack of documentation for using win32com to interact with Office applications, that's because it's all here in the [VBA Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/) and just needs to be converted into python accordingly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After doing more testing, I've figured it out. Here's a piece of what I made with sample data I had laying around. Note the line `ch.ChartType    = 5 # Pie chart` as this answers the question. Yes, the graphs and charts can be accessed via the API, and ChartTypes can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcharttype). This answers the specific question, as well as the greater question of how to take data that exists outside of Office and load it into a chart to be sent through Outlook via the API.

```
from win32com import client
from random import randint

labels  = []
ch_data = []

for x,y in _data:
    labels.append(x)
    ch_data.append(y)

_range = range(1,len(labels)+1)
l_plot = map(lambda x: 'A'+str(x),_range)
d_plot = map(lambda x: 'B'+str(x),_range)
start_end = '{}:{}'.format(l_plot[0],d_plot[-1])

excel         = client.Dispatch('excel.application')
excel.Visible = True # optional
wb            = excel.Workbooks.Add()
ws            = wb.Worksheets.Add()

cnt           = 0
for i in l_plot:
    ws.Range(i).Value = labels[cnt]
    cnt += 1

cnt           = 0
for i in d_plot:
    ws.Range(i).Value = ch_data[cnt]
    cnt += 1

chs             = ws.ChartObjects()
co              = chs.Add(100,0,250,250)
ch              = co.Chart
ch.HasTitle     = True
ch.ChartTitle.Text = 'Chart Title'
ch.ChartType    = 5 # Pie chart

series          = ch.SeriesCollection()
series.Extend(ws.Range(start_end))
co.Copy()

outlook = client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.Display() # required to paste chart
mail.To = 'alias@email.com'
mail.Subject = 'Test Mail Item with Chart'
mail.HTMLBody = '<h3>Hello sir. This is a test</h3><br><br>'

inspector = mail.GetInspector
editor = inspector.WordEditor
editor.Select()
editor.Application.Selection.Start = editor.Application.Selection.End
editor.Application.Selection.Paste()

mail.HTMLBody += '<p>I\'m glad this is finally figured out</p>'
mail.Send()
```

Comment: can you put sample data that you were using?